# Dealing with null data from Apollo GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

just wondering what best way is to deal with null data, that is passed in as a variable to {useQuery} here. Currently I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined" whenever the categoryId is null. I didn't include my graphQL query as it's probably not necessary. Thanks in advance.

```
const RelatedContent = ({categories}) => {

const {data, loading, error} = useQuery(GET_TITLES_BY_CATEGORY, {
    variables: {
        categoryId: categories.edges[0].node.databaseId
    },
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'
})

if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>

if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`

return (
    <div className={styles.sectionBackground + " section"}>
        <div className="container">
            <h3 className={styles.title}>Related film and TV</h3>
            <div className="columns is-multiline is-mobile">
                {
                    data.impactArticles.edges.map((item) => {
                        return (
                            <div className="column">
                                <ContentCard 
                                    item={item}
                                />
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error reads "Cannot read property 'node' of undefined", so you are attempting to access a property on a value that is undefined. In this case, it would be `categories.edges[0]`. If you have an empty array, accessing the first element in that array will result in a value of `undefined`. In other words, you're assuming that `edges` will always have at least one element and that's not the case. So your code needs to reflect that fact. What you do about it (skip the query, pass in some other variable, etc.) depends entirely on your business requirements so we can't answer that for you.

Comment: Ok thank you. Would you be able to tell me how I would conditionally return a statement like "No Related Titles Exist", instead of it throwing an error?

Comment: You can skip your query by using the `skip` parameter, for example: `skip: !categories.edges.length`. Then you can use the same condition to conditionally render whatever alternative UI. Just make sure you fix your variables as well: `categoryId: categories.edges.length && categories.edges[0].node.databaseId`